# Android i want to animate-down my Enter number Layout and place it on top of bottom Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to hide my keypad while keypad collapse image clicks and animate my dialPad enter number relative layout to upside of bottom call layout

[image: my screen while app open]

[image: my screen after clicking on keypad collapse image]

But i want to animate my enter number edittext layout to place up on bottom layout, please anyone help me.

This is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private GridView gridView;
private TextView grid_num_tv;
private EditText phone_num_edt;
private RelativeLayout gridView_collapse_rl, dialPad_overflow_rl, dialPad_num_edt_rl;
private ImageView dialPad_collapse_iv;
static final String[] GRID_NUM = new String[] {
    "1", "2", "3", 
    "4", "5", "6", 
    "7" ,"8", "9" ,
    "*", "0", "#"};
static final String[] GRID_LETTERS = new String[] {
    " ", "abc", "def", 
    "ghi", "jkl", "mno", 
    "pqrs" ,"tuv", "wxyz" ,
    " ", "+", " "};
Context context;
ArrayList<GridListDataModel> myGridList = new ArrayList<GridListDataModel>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    phone_num_edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dial_pad_num_editText);
    gridView_collapse_rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.dial_close_rl);
    dialPad_overflow_rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.dial_overflow_rl);
    dialPad_collapse_iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dialpad_collapse_imageView);

    dialPad_num_edt_rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.dial_num_edt_rl);

    gridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    gridView.setAdapter(new CustomGridAdapter(this, GRID_NUM));


    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            grid_num_tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_num_textView);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), grid_num_tv.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    gridView_collapse_rl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(gridView.isShown()){
                dialPad_collapse_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_collapse);
                gridView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else{
                dialPad_collapse_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_expand);
                gridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml is my main layout xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.gridviewdemo.MainActivity" >


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/dialpad_bottom_rl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dial_overflow_rl"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dial_close_rl"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dialpad_call_imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dial_close_rl"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dialpad_collapse_imageView"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_expand" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dial_overflow_rl"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dialpad_overflow_imageView"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow" />
    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>

 <GridView
     android:id="@+id/gridView1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_above="@+id/dialpad_bottom_rl"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:numColumns="3" >

</GridView>

  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/dial_num_edt_rl"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gridView1"
      android:layout_above="@+id/gridView1"
      android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="189dp" >

      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/dial_pad_num_editText"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
          android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/backspace_imageView"
          android:ems="10"
          android:hint="Enter number" >

          <requestFocus />
      </EditText>

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/backspace_imageView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_action_backspace" />
  </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

grid_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_num_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:text="2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_letter_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/grid_num_textView"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="abc"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

   </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly your layout was, so i write an example here, hope it can help you.
The key here is *android:animateLayoutChanges="true"* in your container layout.
I assume that your "enter number" is my tv_b, and the keypad is tv_a.

Here is the layout:

activity_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/btn_animate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Animate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_a"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_animate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ABCCC" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_b"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tv_a"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ABCCD" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And activity code:
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        Button btnAnimate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_animate);
        final TextView tva = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_a);
        final TextView tvb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_b);
        btnAnimate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (tva.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    tva.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    tva.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You will see animation when click button Animate.

Answer (score 0):

res/anim/scale.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="100%"
    android:pivotY="100%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />

</set>
```

use this scale animation for that layout on button click as below:

```
Animation animation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.scale);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
gridView.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: thanks  @Amrut the code you have suggested looks, its animate the gridview, my problem is i want to place the enter number layout in top of the bottom layout after animation completes

Comment: can you post complete xml of your layout?

Comment: yes, i attached my xml files too. could you please help me ?